# How to plot discrete signals (delta equation)?

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

> Plot 2 discrete signals:
>
> 1. `x[n] = delta[n] - delta[n-1] + delta[n+4]`
> 2. `y[n] = 0.5^n*u[n]`
>
> Also plot the convolution.

I don't know what the delta is supposed to be and how to approach these kind of signals. If I have a simple signal, I know how to do it.

```
n = 0:7; 
x1 = cos(pi*n); 
subplot(1,2,1) 
stem(n,x1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the dirac (delta) function in matlab will not work for discrete functions as the outcome is Inf at n=0. Instead use the value 1 at the right locations. Furthermore, u[n] is the step function or in matlab the heaviside function. It is zero for negative x and 1 for positive x, making a step at exactly x = 0.

The following code will plot all your functions:

```
n = -5:5
x = [0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0]; %x[n] from n =-5 to n=5

%y = 0.5.^n .* heaviside(n); %[y[n] from n =-5 to n=5
y = 0.5.^n .* [0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1]; %stepfunction from n =-5 to n=5 
z = conv(x,y); %z[n] from n = -10 to n=10

subplot(3,1,1);stem(n,y1)
subplot(3,1,2);stem(n,y2)
subplot(3,1,3);stem(-10:10,y3)
```

Comment: MATLAB’s `Heaviside` is 0.5 at n=0. The discrete unit step u[n] is usually defined as being 1 at 0.

Comment: You are right, better to implement the step function by hand.

Answer (score 0):

It appears to the be the [Dirac delta](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/dirac.html) function. Which has a function in Matlab.

```
x = dirac(n)
```

Also, the [convolution](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/conv.html) of two functions has a function.

```
w = conv(u,v)
```

Not knowing the interval you have for these, I can't say. I could generate some code. Also the function u is unknown.

Comment: Ty for the dirac function.Its very strange because the u(n) wasn't specified in the exercies.It was only said to generate those signals and also it isn't specified the interval.

Comment: Ask your teacher unless you can figure out u(n), just email them. Or the TA. As that u(n) isn't a common name for anything.

Comment: u(t) and u[n] are the continuous and discrete unit step functions, the integral of &delta;(t) and &delta;[n].

Comment: I've usually seen H

Comment: [Oppenheim and Willsky](https://www.amazon.com/Signals-Systems-2nd-Alan-Oppenheim/dp/0138147574) use *u* for the unit step function. I’m sure not all books follow the same convention.